# Refining typescript disjoint union

Tags: typescript, disjoint-union

I am trying to get something like the following to work, however typescript is outputting errors on trying to access the `o.foo` property:

```js
type Base = { s: string };
type Extra = { foo: string; };
type Other = { bar: string; };
type T = Base & (Extra | Other);

function f(o: T): string {
    if (typeof o.foo === 'string') {
        return o.s + o.foo;
    }
    return o.s + o.bar;
}
```

The error is

```
Property 'foo' does not exist on type 'T'.
  Property 'foo' does not exist on type 'Base & Other'.
```

It seems like typescript is unable to correctly infer that if `o` has a `foo` property, that is a string, then the type of `o` must be in the `Base & Extra` branch of the union.

Is there any way to make it understand this?

Comment: This is possible in flow (see "Disjoint Unions" in https://flow.org/en/docs/types/unions/#toc-unions-refinements) but I'm not sure it works in typescript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't access members of a union unless they are common. You can use an `in` typeguard instead:

```
type Base = { s: string };
type Extra = { foo: string; };
type Other = { bar: string; };
type T = Base & (Extra | Other);

function f(o: T): string {
    if ('foo' in o) {
        return o.s + o.foo;
    }
    return o.s + o.bar;
}
```